# Reload PHP code after Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am still learning here folks, so excuse my code if its messy.
I have 3 separate pages as follow:
AccountView.php---Where the data is shown:

```
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="opentasks">
                        <!-- view Open tasks -->
                            <?php $task= new acct; echo $task->accountActiveTasks()?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end view open tasks -->
                        <!-- start adding quick task -->
                          <div class="chat-form">
                             <!--  <form method="post" action="addTask.php"> -->
                              <div class="input-cont ">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12" placeholder="Add a quick Task..." name ="quicktask" id="quicktask">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="pull-right chat-features">
                                      <a href="javascript:;">
                                          <i class="icon-camera"></i>
                                      </a>
                                      <a href="javascript:;">
                                          <i class="icon-link"></i>
                                      </a>
                                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="AddTask" value="Add" onclick="add_quick_task()">


                                      <input type="hidden" name="acct" id="acct" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['acctname']?>">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php $username = $_SESSION['username']; echo $username?>"> 
                                  </div>
                              </div>
```

tasks.js --> graps one input from AccountView.php

```
function add_quick_task(){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{

                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("microsodt.XMLHTTP");
            }

        var acct = document.getElementById('acct').value;
        var quicktask = document.getElementById('quicktask').value;
        // var taskstatus = 'Active';
        var user = document.getElementById('user').value;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
                document.getElementById('panel-body').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }   
        }
            url = "addTask.php?acct="+acct+"&quicktask="+quicktask+"&user="+user;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
```

account_functions.php ---Where the PHP function gets the data from mysql

```
     public function accountActiveTasks(){
      $varacctname = $_REQUEST['acctname'];
      $varViewActiveTasks = mysql_query("SELECT * from tasks WHERE taskresource='$varacctname' && taskstatus='Active'");

      while ($rows= mysql_fetch_array($varViewActiveTasks)) {
           $this->accttask = $rows['tasktitle'];
           $this->acctTaskStatus = $rows['taskstatus'];
           $this->acctTaskOwner = $rows['taskowner'];

                              echo "<div class=\"timeline-messages\">

                          <div class=\"msg-time-chat\">
                              <a href=\"#\" class=\"message-img\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"img/chat-avatar.jpg\" alt=\"\"></a>
                              <div class=\"message-body msg-in\">
                                  <span class=\"arrow\"></span>
                                  <div class=\"text\">
                                      <p class=\"attribution\"><a href=\"#\">$this->acctTaskOwner at 1:55pm, 13th April 2013</a></p>
                                      <p> $this->accttask</p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- /comment -->
                      </div>";
      }
```

My goal is that every time the tasks.js runs, the php code in AccountView.php is refreshed. sort of like appending the data. Currently the data gets pushed to the mysql table but i have to refresh to see it. I would like for it to show automatically on success.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697755/reload-php-code-with-ajax?rq=1

Comment: what is the point of using ajax when you reload your page anyway?

Comment: i don't want to reload the page, i just want to append the data. i will post an image to show you what i mean..

Comment: sorry can't post image due to reputation. its similar to a chat window.

Comment: I think you have seen my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

window.location.reload();

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but i still don't want all the page to be reloaded. otherwise there is not point of Ajax i am assuming.

Answer (score 0):

What is panel-body that is a class.In the response you are adding response to it i think your intention is to have id="panel-body"

If you want to append the response to the "panel-body" Div you may use this jquery statement

```
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            $('#panel-body').append(xmlhttp.responseText);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan, but this didn't work. i created opentasks id surrounding the PHP code in Accountsview.php but still couldn't accomplish it.

Comment: You can do one thing in ajax call after updation of data try to get the new data what you want to have, as response and write that into your Div